# Handling Strings in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell

```
"-Project:Abcdefg -Version: 1.2.3 -Channel: Some Random Text -Parametre: Some Random Text Again"
```

I Want to extract only `"Version: 1.2.3"` from the string above.

Can you please suggest some easy method for this extraction of string ?

Comment: [1] please add formatting markers around your sample data so that it is both easily readable AND is clearly laid out. [2] what have you tried? what did not work? [3] please take the Tour for this site before your Question gets removed due to not following the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alternative, you could also use the regex `-replace` for this as in

```
$str = "-Project:Abcdefg -Version: 145.126.110 -Channel: Some Random Text -Parametre: Some Random Text Again"
$str -replace '.*(Version:\s*[\d.]+).*', '$1'
```

Output:

```
Version: 145.126.110
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Theo. The solution worked perfectly. Can you please suggest some online free sources to get more detailed knowledge about powershell or any books that can be referred to study Powershell?

Comment: @AkshayChouksey There is tons of free learning material to be found on the web. For instance [1] [Learn PowerShell](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell/index.htm), [2] [Getting Started With Microsoft PowerShell](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiV8rrwhv_rAhXizoUKHYl8DRYQFjAAegQIARAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.docs.is.ed.ac.uk%2Fskills%2Fdocuments%2F3835%2F3835.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2z4HoHQcZJ5_fgSCDN74ts),

Comment: @AkshayChouksey  [3] [Windows PowerShell Step by Step](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiV8rrwhv_rAhXizoUKHYl8DRYQFjACegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoftpressstore.com%2Fcontent%2Fimages%2F9780735675117%2Fsamplepages%2F9780735675117.pdf&usg=AOvVaw05Yi9NH-Ij6tf8xDN9z8sD), [4] [Learning PowerShell](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiV8rrwhv_rAhXizoUKHYl8DRYQFjAFegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Friptutorial.com%2FDownload%2Fpowershell.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1S9L-HxrBzt8KcZgyUmo_I) and lots more.. and of course **this site**

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, because - as Lee said - this question is laid out poorly, but I'm thinking you mean to extract "Version: 1.2.3" from the full string.

You can use `Select-String`.

```
$str = "-Project:Abcdefg -Version: 1.2.3 -Channel: Some Random Text -Parametre: Some Random Text Again"
Select-String -InputObject $str -SimpleMatch "Version: 1.2.3"
```

If it's a dynamic value, you'll want regex.

```
$str = "-Project:Abcdefg -Version: 1.2.3 -Channel: Some Random Text -Parametre: Some Random Text Again"

([regex]::matches($str, "Version: \d+\.\d+\.\d+", "IgnoreCase")).Value
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the Solution you provided. Yes the string will be dynamic and also the version can have multiple digits for eg. 12.13.158 or 145.126.110 or 1.2.30. I just want to avoid the hardcoded solutions.

Comment: I've updated to match what you need. The \d+ will match any digit, any number of times.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Davis. The solution you provided worked for me.